# perl decode string in cyrillic

Tags: mysql, perl, encoding, utf-8, logging

I've got a problem with the following string:

```
$str="this is \321\213\321\213\321\213\321\213\321\213 \321\201\320\277\320\260\321\200\321\202\320\260\321\200";
```

This string is located in an ascii text file and I want to store in a Mysql db (utf8). \321\231 ... are cyrillic symbols.

### What can I do to make \321\213 look like cyrillic characters in Mysql db

This should be described in RFC2047, end look like it was utf7 to utf8 conversion.. dont know excatly.
its "unicode escape"

**working variant:**

```
use Encode::Escape;
$var1='\321\213';
         print decode 'unicode-escape', $var1;
#correct mysql view in phpmyadmin
$dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:database=test', 'testuser', 'testpass', { mysql_enable_utf8 => 1});
```

Comment: What encoding are those symbols in?

Comment: they are utf8 "Quoted-Printable" encoded \320\263\320\270  -- this is 2 letters \321\263 first \320\270 second.

Comment: I don't understand - how can `321` be a byte value (0..255)? But maybe I'm just not familiar with this specific notation

Comment: @pekka: i wondered too, but it returned to "this is ыыыы\xD1 спарта\xD1" and this is cyrillic.

Comment: @MealstroM: Are you sure the source data is quoted-printable encoded? I don't think QP uses a backslash as part of it's symbols. It looks like those are either characters for a variable length encoding, or unicode characters. Do you know for sure that the source data is UTF8?

Comment: ive found this for python result.decode('unicode-escape').encode('raw-unicode-escape')

Comment: @Pekka, these are octal values, so \321 is 209

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not quoted-printable at all. This is Perl quoted string representation, also know as `PERLQQ`, of a series of octets. The numbers are octal.

These bytes encode UTF-8 for the most part, but the data contain two errors. Looks like one half of a character each somehow fell off. I have marked it with arrows just below.

```
my $octets = "this is \321\213\321\213\321\213\321\213\321 \321\201\320\277\320\260\321\200\321\202\320\260\321";
#                                                     ↑↑↑↑                                                 ↑↑↑↑
```

This invalid in UTF-8, but can be repaired. We put the [Unicode replacement character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replacement_character).

```
use Encode qw(decode);
my $characters = decode 'UTF-8', $octets, Encode::FB_DEFAULT | Encode::LEAVE_SRC;
# this is ыыыы� спарта�
```

This character string can now be simply inserted into the database as usual. The DSN in the `connect` call for DBI or DBIx::Class must include the attribute [`mysql_enable_utf8`](http://p3rl.org/DBD%3a%3amysql#mysql_enable_utf8).

```
connect('DBI:mysql:foobar;mysql_enable_utf8=1', …, …);
```

Comment: This didnt helped. Answer with **$var= decode 'unicode escape', $var; was correct. or isnt. but works**
and $dbh = DBI->connect($config->{sql}->{DBI}, $config->{sql}->{user}, $config->{sql}->{pass}, { mysql_enable_utf8 => 1 }); helped me with correct mysql web view.
 **why this didnt work for me?**

Comment: You changed the problem! First you had an interpolating string `"…\321\213…"`, then after your edit it became a non-interpolating string `'\321\213'`. There's a big difference, you know.

Comment: Ive got a lot of strings in this encoding. The original strings have both cyrr and latin words, but in my log files ive got only strings like **"\321\231...\321\231.. some words in latin"**. i just need to put em all in correct way to mysqldb to be able to view them as original strings. thats all. i've made mistake in subject that couse this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert explicitly the codes to characters. For that you need to know what's the input encoding. I suppose it's iso-8859-5, but it could be windows-1252 or something else.

```
use Encode qw( decode );

my $str="this is \321\213\321\213\321\213\321\213\321 \321\201\320\277\320\260\321\200\321\202\320\260\321";
my $out .= from_to( "iso-8859-5","utf-8", $str );
```

I've just seen that your source string is indeed QP, so you need to convert from QP to bytes; that's easy, simply use [MIME::QuotedPrint](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/MIME-Base64-3.13/QuotedPrint.pm):

```
use MIME::QuotedPrint ();

my $out = MIME::QuotedPrint::decode($str);
```

Comment: The answer does not fit to the question. Why didn't you just try out your code? It produces mojibake.

Comment: @daxim: I have no cyrillic fonts installed, I can't see anything anyway, I must suppose the OP provided the right information.

Answer (score -2):

Problem is: perl does not know that the string is UTF-8, so you must turn flag explicitly on.

`Encode::_utf8_on($str);`

Comment: -1 This is the wrong way to go about handling encoded data. See http://p3rl.org/UNI for the proper API.